# Conver Raw files to .jpg file VB.net

Tags: vb.net, image, image-conversion

i'm trying to convert any Raw pictures to .jpeg format.while creating `bitmap` object  for .CR2 image 23mb file. it throws `OutOfMemoryexception`  at this line `Dim img As Bitmap = Image.FromFile(path1)`. the below code is helps you to understand my question.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dr As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If dr = DialogResult.OK Then
            path1 = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            If Not Path.GetFileName(path1).EndsWith(".jpeg") Then
                Dim img As Bitmap = Image.FromFile(path1)
                Dim b=ConvertImageTypeToJPEG(img)
                 pb1.Image = Image.FromStram(b)
            else
            pb1.Image = Image.FromFile(path1)
            End If
        
        Else
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function ConvertImageTypeToJPEG(Image As Bitmap) As Stream
        Dim SaveStream As New IO.MemoryStream
        Image.Save(SaveStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Return SaveStream
    End Function
```

i don't know what i'm missing!

In the `Image.FromFile` documentation, an `OutOfMemoryException` can be throw if:

The file does not have a valid image format.

-or-

GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

if anyone has the experience on this problem can help me.

Comment: What you're missing is the fact that, if using a type or method doesn't work, you should be reading the documentation for that type or method to make sure that you understand it and are using it properly. Not surprisingly, the documentation for the `Image.FromFile` method answers your question, so it should never have had to be posted.

Comment: i'm very sorry to waste your time @jmcilhinney. i'm a beginner in vb.net.i have already seen that documentation.what i learned from is the file path```path1``` is actually not having an proper image format.i have already mention in my question about my file type.i have no idea for how can i handle this exception.

Comment: You can use [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET) (ImageMagick for .Net). See the [Read raw image from camera](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/docs/ReadRawImageFromCamera.md) quick docs.

Comment: thank you very much @jimi i'll try it and if it is solves , I'll inform you.